# Spring Boot - not getting a validation errors

Tags: spring, validation, thymeleaf

I'm trying to validate the form. Spring correctly validates, but when errors should be returned, it receives an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'employee' available as request attribute
```

Add I don't know what is wrong. Could you help me?

Controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/employee/add",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addEmployee(@Valid DTOEmployee dtoEmployee, BindingResult result) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "employee_add";
        }
        employeeService.save(dtoEmployee);

        return "redirect:/employee?add";
    }
```

DTOEmployee:

```
public class DTOEmployee{

        @NotNull
        private String name;
        @NotNull
        private String subname;
        @NotNull
        private String email;

    }
```

fragments of employee_add:

```
 <form th:action="@{/employee/add}" th:object="${employee}" method="post" class="form-inline justify-content-center">
                                    <div class="input-group my-1">
                                        <input th:field="*{name}" type="text" id="name" class="form-control"
                                                    placeholder="Your name"/>
                                        <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Name error</p>
            <input th:field="*{subname}" type="text" id="name" class="form-control"
                                                    placeholder="Your subname"/>
                                        <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('subname')}" th:errors="*{name}">Name error</p>
                                        <input th:field="*{email}" type="email" id="email" class="form-control"
                                                    placeholder="Your mail"/>
                                        <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}">Name error</p>

                                    </div>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                </form>
```

messages.properties:

```
NotNull.DTOEmployee.name = Name must be not null
NotNull.DTOEmployee.subname= Subname must be not null
NotNull.DTOEmployee.email= Email must be not null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are mixing thymeleaf form submission with requests. As stated in the example from spring.io https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

```
@PostMapping("/greeting")
public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting) {
    return "result";
}
```

Seems you are missing `@ModelAttribute`

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I`m added @ModelAttribute [ public String addEmployee(@Valid @ModelAttribute DTOEmployee dtoEmployee, BindingResult result)] and I get the following exception:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "employee_add" - line 44, col 44)] with root cause
```

line 44 in employee_add is:

```
<input th:field="*{name}" type="text" id="name" class="form-control"
```

#### EDIT:

I forgot to add the attribute name in quotes:

```
public String addEmployee(@Valid @ModelAttribute("employee") DTOEmployee dtoEmployee, BindingResult result)
```

It`s work :)